# master node in a hadoop cluster became inactive how to make it up and running

Tags: hadoop

i am using 3 node cluster one is master node and rest are slave node. my master node became inactive, its not getting pinged. how to make it up and running. the error its showing is  No Route to Host from  Hadoop-slave2/ip address to Hadoop-master:9000 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Comment: `No Route to Host` means the system you are trying to ping is offline. Check whether the system is online.

Comment: yes system is online. i have ip address also in my hosts file

Comment: What is your ping command? Did you give `hostname` or `IP address`?

Comment: Can you do this on your namenode system: `ping your-namenode-ip` and `ping your-namenode-hostname`? What is the result?

Comment: network error:connection time out.  this message is getting displayed

Comment: When do you get this error: `network error:connection time out`? When you give `IP` or `hostname` or `Both`?

Answer (score 0):

Restart your namenode system and then try to ping it from slave node (If possible).

Else, do this and post the results of each command:

1. `ping hostname`
2. `ping 127.0.0.1`
3. `telnet hostname`
4. `telnet hostname port`
5. `ps -aux | grep "port-number"`

> **Note:** Type this all in namenode system and post the results.

Comment: my vm only got crashed. do you know how to make it run again